# Is it possible to compare a char with &char or &mut char?

Tags: rust

I am writing a lexer in Rust, and I am quite new to how Rust does things in comparison to Java / C++.

I have a function that goes something like:

```
fn lookup(next_char: &mut char, f: &File) {
    //if or match
    if next_char == '(' {
        //do something
    }
}
```

This gives

```
error: the trait `core::cmp::PartialEq<char>` is not implemented for the type `&mut char` [E0277]
     if next_char == '(' {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If they are switched, then it gives a mismatched types error. I understand why it gives these two errors. I was wondering if there was some way to compare the two values. Perhaps I am not thinking in the Rust way or something, but I have not seen a good way to do this in the documentation or elsewhere online.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just have to dereference to get the `char` value out of the reference:

```
if *next_char == '(' {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Or, less idiomatically, take a reference of the literal: `if next_char == &'('`

Comment: Oh there's a blanked impl for &T == &T

Comment: Sure. You just have to have the same amount of references on each side. Or do you mean taking a reference to a literal? It just implicitly makes a local variable, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Or, maybe even more idiomatic, with pattern matching:

```
match *next_char {
    '(' => // ...
}
```

although if you branch on only one character the if-then is probably a better choice.